# Is there an attribute in C++ to throw a fatal compiler error upon ignored return type?

Tags: c++, attributes

I am looking for a harsher version of `[[nodiscard]]` that throws an fatal error instead of a warning when a return value is ignored. So for example:

```
[[harshnodiscard]] int getSize() { return 0; }
```

Any code that ignores the return value of `getSize` should not compile.

Is there any functionality for this?

Comment: Why do you want that? Somebody who does not want to make a mistake will not ignore warnings and somebody how wants to discard the value can always do so by assignment to std::ignore.

Comment: @gerum I want it because there are times where ignoring the return values of a functor will lead to potential memory leaks. What if I have a function that returns a heap allocated object? I want that to be assigned to something, not just dangling.

Comment: @beangod Return a unique_ptr?

Comment: @EricMSchmidt I just want a general way of strictly enforcing the usage of return values. Even though memory is my main reason for this, I want to treat the discarding of return values of functions like getSize as logical errors too.

Comment: I think the best you can do is using -Werror